# Face Recognisation for login using django

Tags: django, python-3.x, web

I am trying to implement a facial recognition login system but I have an error "Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (128,) (0,)" and I have no idea what or how can I solve it. Here are my view.py and facedetector.py that have been implemented and the error that I get from my server:

link to complete project https://github.com/Vampboy/Face-Recognition-Login-System
someone has already asked this question previously [Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (128,) (0,) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621789/operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes-128-0-error/57094220?noredirect=1#comment100709936_57094220)  but didn't get much response.
probably because he didn't provided complete code.

Blelow is error I am getting:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/base/

Django Version: 2.2.3
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'pages']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/tiktok/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/tiktok/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/tiktok/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/var/www/django_app/djangoproject/mysite/pages/views.py" in base
  54.                                 if facedect(user.userprofile.head_shot.url):

File "/var/www/django_app/djangoproject/mysite/pages/views.py" in facedect
  33.                 check=face_recognition.compare_faces(face_1_face_encoding, face_encodings)

File "/home/tiktok/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py" in compare_faces
  222.     return list(face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding_to_check) <= tolerance)

File "/home/tiktok/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py" in face_distance
  72.     return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)

Exception Type: ValueError at /base/
Exception Value: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (128,) (0,)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for `face_recognition.compare_faces` function should be a list as [stated in the documentation](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#recognize-faces-in-images-and-identify-who-they-are). Change your `djangoproject/mysite/pages/views.py` line 33 to:

```
check=face_recognition.compare_faces([face_1_face_encoding], face_encodings)
```

To solve the cause of the exception.